# How does ALL (tablename/columnname) work when used as 2nd parameter of CALCULATE?

Tags: powerbi, dax

The model has sales fact and product dimension. There is M:1 relationship on product_id column.

Assume there is a table visual with 2 columns: Product name and a measure.

Following are 2 sub-questions -

1. Question regarding measure 1:

Measure 1 =

```
CALCULATE(

        COUNT(Sales[SalesId]),

        ALL('Product')

    )
```

Does ALL remove the filter from the product table from the sales table or does ALL return the unfiltered product table that leads to clearing of the filter context? Since table expansion happens only towards the 1 side, then how does un-filtering on product affect the sales calculation? Just trying to visualize the underlying logic of how the un-filtering works.

2. Question regarding Measure2:
   Code:

   Measure2 =
   CALCULATE(

   COUNT(Sales[SalesId]),

   ALL('Product'[ProductName])

   )

ALL returns a single column (ProductName) table with all filters removed and there is no table expansion happening here so how does it logically work? Again I'm trying to visualize the underlying logic of how the un-filtering works.

Answer (score 1):

ALL used as a filter argument is filter modifier.
It removes the filter on its argument.

When the argument is a table, it removes the filter over the entire expanded table (the table specified as argument).
Whent the argument is one or more columns, it removes the filters over the specified columns.

Filter removals happen during the fourth step in the `CALCULATE` execution, after the context transition and before the expression evaluation

The explanation of the `CALCULATE` execution step can be found in the [DAX Guide](https://dax.guide/calculate/)

In the Measure 1, all filters are removed from the `'Product'` table.
In the Measure 2, only the filter existing over `'Product'[Name]` is removed

In recent DAX verisions, when used as a filter modifier, `ALL` can be replaced by `REMOVEFILTERS`

Comment: Expanded table in your answer is the table in 1st param (sales) or 2nd param (product)?

Comment: the tables specified as argument. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: 1) So in measure 1 we have expanded Product table. Does the count happen on sales or product expanded table? 2) Similarly, in measure 2 we have filter over existing table removed. Which existing table- sales or product?

Comment: 1. The count happens on Sales table. The Product expanded table might be coincident with the basic Product table, if there are no many to one relationships between Product and other tables, like ProductSubcategory for instance. The effect of the filter over Product has an impact on the Sales expaned table, on its part corresponding to the Product table. 2. We have the removal of the filter over the 'Product'[ProductName] column only. This affects both the Product table and the Sales expanded table, where the filter over the column corresponding to Product[ProductName] is removed.

Comment: In measure 1 as per evaluation order does the sales or the product table get expanded 1st? I think product and then the product expanded table acts as a filter context to the sales expanded table. Have I got this right?

Comment: Yes. But consider that tables expanstion is just a logic concept and not an operation that happens phisically. What happens is that all the filters existing over the portion of Sales expanded table corresponding to the Product expanded table are removed. What matters is the order of execution of the steps of CALCULATE. Here is an articole I joust found about this https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/order-of-evaluation-in-calculate-parameters/